# Transform list to have have only one item within a range

Tags: scala, scala-collections

```
val test = List[Int](50, 115, 200, 50, 30, 22, 175, 350, 5000)
```

If I have a list like this and I want to reduce it down so that any values within 50 of each other are considered duplicates but I want to retain one of the values.

I have this right now but it removed all the ones within 50 of each other where I want to keep the highest one each time.

```
test.filter(x => !test.exists(v => if(v == x) false else Math.abs(v - x) < 50));
List(115, 350, 5000)
```

So ideally this list would then include 50 and 200 as well.

EDIT:
I actually ended up wanting to do this for a map.

```
val tmap = Map[String, String]("57" -> "550", "145" -> "2000", "85" -> "78", "40" -> "8556")
```

Where I want to look at all the keys within 50 and then get the one with the highest number value each time they are within that range. Any not within the range I keep also. I would want to result here to be.

```
Map(145 -> 2000, 40 -> 8556)
```

Maybe I should make a new question?

Comment: How do you want to handle a case where you have(1, 50, 99, 148)? Would this return one because the first is within 50 of the second which is within 50 of the third which is within 50 of the fourth? which one would you want to save? Would simply creating a bucket x/50 is enough for you or do you need something more dynamic?

Comment: I would want to return 148 @assaf-mendelson

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you're after?

```
val res = test.sorted.foldRight(List[Int]()) {
  (z, l) =>
    if (l.isEmpty) List(z)
    else if (l.head - z > 50) z +: l
    else l
}
```

Output: `List(50, 115, 200, 350, 5000)`

Answer (score 0):

```
myMap
  .toSeq
  .sortWith(_._1.toLong < _._1.toLong)
  .foldLeft(Seq[(String, String)])((x, y) => {
    if(x.isEmpty) y +: x
    else if(Math.abs(x.last._1.toLong - y._1.toLong) < 50) {
      if(x.last._2.toLong < y._2.toLong) y +: x.dropRight(1)
      else x
    }
    else y +: x
  })
```

I think this does what i want for the second part of my question. Inspired by Toms answers above.